# SSL certificates for internal and external dns

Tags: ssl, dns

I am trying to get a valid ssl certificate on a captive portal implementation.
Due to the limitation that I cannot get a valid ssl for internal ips I need some help from you guys by validating my thougs

Here is my ideas

1. Get a valid domain name for my goal from godaddy or whatever 
       (something like captiveportals.com)
2. Use a subdomain for every captive portal gateway ej :
   gateway1.captive....
3. Buy a valid ssl certificate for each gateway.

I know that it is ok but....

**My question:**

On the captive portal I have an internal DNS where the internal ip example... 192.168.1.10 will map to gateway1.captiveportals.com

that same domain will have an external ip for manage pruposes... so ussing google dns for example gateway1.captiveportals.com will resolve a public ip.

**QUESTION**: Will the ssl certificate still be valid for internal users that will be ussing internal dns ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the validation of a certificate it only matters that the hostname in the URL matches the subject(s) of the certificate. It does not matter which IP address the hostname resolves to.

But, since you are trying to use the certificate in a captive portal: a TLS certificate for the captive portal can be used to access the portal directly but it can not be used to redirect other https requests to the portal. For example if your certificate is for `captive.example.org` and the user tries to access `https://www.example.com` and this access is redirected to your captive portal then the certificate validation will fail because the name in the URL does not match the certificates subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in my case the captive portal does redirect the client and change the url... So it's not a problem, I will accept the answer tomorrow to check ... Thanks again for your time

Comment: @NoelCarcases: to redirect somebody from `https://original.site` to `https://captive.portal` you would need to have a valid certificate for original.site first. But you only have one for captive.portal.

Comment: I will buy two certificates :D I have never asked for the second one because is the same situation that the first one

Comment: On the actual captive portal when a user try to open google.com for example the firewall redirect the user to the captive portal and change the url to this format https://captive_portal_hostname?get_parameters_whit_destination_host. I have modified the captive portal with some scripts and inside the portal I do some https calls to another local site. That´s the reason why I will buy two ssl certiicates one to the captive portal and another to the other local site

Comment: @NoelCarcases: If the user types google.com  the browser (at least Chrome and Firefox) will actually access `https://google.com` because they know that this site should only be accessed with https. This means that your capture portal would need to have a certificate for google.com which is accepted by the browser. Without this certificate you cannot issue the redirect away from google.com.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I can confirm that it's working now so thanks you all for your advice